# Automatically Adding Columns to an SSIS Script Component

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a datasource whose output is connected to a Script Component. When i add some columns to the datasource. I should go to Script component and check the newly added columns as inputs. Is there any way that i can automate this process.

It should automatically select the inputs when ever there is a change in the Data Source columns.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that's not possible with the Script Component in SSIS.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this in SSIS. I have a dataSource table which adds new columns frequently. How can i get all the newly added columns eachtime with out editing the package?